# SCSS: add adjacent siblings with for loop

Tags: sass

I'm trying to achieve the following code with a scss for loop:

```
.box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.box + .box {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.box + .box + .box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
...
```

My for loop in scss looks like this:

```
.box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;

  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
      $sel: if($i == 1, &, selector-nest($sel, &)) !global;

      #{$sel} {
        @if ($i % 2 == 0) {
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 2%;
        } @else {
          margin-left: 2%;
          margin-right: 0;
        }
      }


  }
}
```

The result is this:

```
.box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.box .box {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.box .box .box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
...
```

But I don't know how i can add the adjacent sibling selector between the classes. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. Is there a better way to do it, or could i use a recursive function or something like that? :)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
.box {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2%;

  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
      $sel: if($i == 1, &, selector-nest(#{$sel} #{'+'}, &)) !global;

      + #{$sel} {
        @if ($i % 2 == 0) {
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 2%;
        } @else {
          margin-left: 2%;
          margin-right: 0;
        }
      }


  }
}
```